# How can I get the entire contents inside of a DIV with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a div on my page and return ALL the contents found inside of it.  By all, I mean the HTML of all formatting, the text, html objects and anything else inside the div.  I cannot seem to find a method that does this.

**EXAMPLE:**

Let's say I have :

```
<div id="div1">
    This is a sample<br/>
    <img src="sample.jpg"/>
</div>
```

I use a simple selector in JQuery to get the div

```
$('#div1'). <what??!>
```

I have tried

```
.text, .contents, .html, .innerHTML
```

I expected .html to do the trick but ...  None of the above will get me the  tag inside and I haven't found another property that I can try.  The ones that get me anything will return the text outside of html elements but nothing else.

The expected outcome is:

```
This is a sample<br/>
<img src="sample.jpg"/>
```

I'm sure it's something simple but why I can't wrap my keyboard around it is beyond me.

**To be a bit more clear about what I'm actually trying to accomplish:**

I have a div with editablecontent turned on.  This allows me to past image data from the clipboard which add an  tag inside the div with base64 data for the src.  I need to capture that added  element and all it's properties.

Comment: jQuery is a lot of fanfare for doing simple DOM crawling and mutations in 2021. I'd advise you to use plain JS as it's pretty much the same for all browsers these days (which was not the case 15 years ago when jQuery was created), and you'll build a marketable skillset. `document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML` should do the trick.

Comment: @RyanWheale Whether or not your suggestion works, it does not answer the question.  I'm fully aware of how to code in javascript but what I was asking about was jQuery because that's the library I'm tasked with using.   And in reality I know how to do it in jQuery but I wasn't getting the results as expected and I assumed it was because I was pasting an image into the div and jQuery was having a hard time with the content after the fact.

Comment: jQuery is just an abstraction over JavaScript - you're not forced to use it for all DOM interactions. I guess all I was trying to say is... if you're having trouble with the abstraction, just use real JavaScript. I promise that whomever mandated jQuery will not fire you over it. If they do, you didn't want to work for that clown anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$("#div1").html()** does the trick, you only need to add the round brackets

The space you see in the output comes from the html, remove the spacing there to get a neat solution

```js
console.log($("#div1").html())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    This is a sample<br/>
    <img src="sample.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What a different a day makes...  I did EXACTLY the selector you used and used all the other selectors I mentioned however after pasting an image into the div I was never getting back the <img> tag data.  It would get all the text and ignore all the tags and I couldn't explain it.  So I assumed jquery was having difficulty reading in the pasted values for some reason..  Turns out I've come back to it today and tried again... and, correct, .html() works... I just don't understand why it didn't yesterday.  Thank you.